# How can I apply a lexicon to a list of sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, lexicon

I have a lexicon dictionary in this shape

```
6   ابن جزمه    1
7   ابو جهل -1
8   اتق الله    -1
9   اتقو الله   1
```

I want to create a new list containing the score of each sentence based on the lexicon adding the score of each word and if no words exist append zero 
when I implement my code I get `len(lex_score) = 3679` after I add elif condition I get `len(lex_score) = 95079`

the len(lex_score) should equal 6064

```
lex_score = []
def lexic(text):
    for tweet in sentences:
        score = 0
        for word in tweet.split():
            if word in lexicon:
                score = score+lexicon[word]
            elif word not in lexicon:
                score = 0
                lex_score.append(score)
```

I want to create a new column in the data frame containing the score of each sentence. what am I doing wrong?
and is there a better way to do so ?

Comment: Can you show your `lexicon` dictionary in python format?  Also, show more code please.  E.g. give an example of `sentences`.

Comment: Note, you can replace the `elif` condition with `else:` if there are no other possible outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can just sum the scores of valid lexicon entries in each tweet, and then append that score to `lex_score` on each iteration of `sentences`.

Note: I'm assuming `text == sentences` - otherwise there's a missing line where `text` is broken down into `sentences`.  Either way, this basic approach should still work:

```
def lexic(text):
    lex_score = []
    for tweet in text: # assuming sentences == text
        score = sum([lexicon[word] for word in tweet.split() if word in lexicon])
        lex_score.append(score)
    return lex_score
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. any Idea If I have another list with negation words how do I handle it with that lexicon ?

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm not sure I understand your negation words question, happy to help if I can.  If it's different enough from your original question, consider opening a separate question.  If this answer resolved your original question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I have a list of negation words and I'm worried they will affect the words in lexicon so I want to take it in my consideration. how can I do so ?

Comment: Can you update your original post with an example, including the impact you're concerned about?